# IOS7: Pop ViewController forces the UIImageView to drop

Tags: ios, ios7

After upgrading my project to iOS7

[image: On Initial Load]

when I do a BACK Button and the UINavigationController goes back to the previous page, an ImageView on the top of the screen shifts down.

[image: images shift down]

I use IB to do my layouts. These are my Simulated Metrics:

[image: Simulated Metrics]

I have AutoLayout off. Any ideas on what the issue might be? I wasnt sure if anyone wants to see specific code and I didnt want to clutter up the question with too much code.

**Updates:** Based on the comment questions, I wanted to make these updates:

- In no place in the application .h or .m file do I make any changes to the imageview's sizes or location.
- In both the `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` I call a user-defined method called `recalculateAll` but their is no reference at all to any imageview sizes. Just for trying it out I commented out the entire section and ran the code and it still jumps down.
- In my `init` I do programatically set some imageviews (you see the #132 in what appears to be a bubble) using their x and y's.

Here is a typical navigation I use for moving from the view controller to the tableviewcontroller:

```
 GetTimeOffByType *showTimeOffReport = [[GetTimeOffByType alloc] initWithNibName:@"GetTimeOffByType" bundle:nil];
    showTimeOffReport.timeOffType = @"Vacation";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:showTimeOffReport animated:YES];
```

These are all `.xib` files, no storyboarding at all. Its basically a view controller which has an embedded `UINavigationController` with 6 buttons. Each time a button is pressed it pushes a `UITableViewController` passing different parameters and showing different data. The transition I am using to get back to the original `UIViewController` is simply the iOS generated `BACK` button (so no code to show for that)

**Update#2** Hopefully this will help someone solve this wierd behavior. So if I were to click on the table view cell on `showTimeOffReport` to get the cell detail and then using BACK navigate all the way back it doesnt jump down.

**Update#3** Ok this is something I just discovered : The issue of jumping down or not is related to the translucency of the UINavigationBar. If you have a Translucent = YES it will start from the top of the window. If you have a translucent = NO it will start from the bottom of the UINavigationBar.

Comment: Are you doing anything related to view frames in the viewWillAppear/viewDidDisappear methods of the presenting view controller?

Comment: @KyleClegg, I am using viewWillAppear so that if something gets updated (its a tabBarApplication), when they switch back to this view controller it will recalculate. What do you mean by "view frames"

Comment: For example with your imageview, I was curious if you are setting its frame programmatically anywhere. In iOS 7 content now underlaps the navigation bar, so people that relied on setting frames to an x,y of 0,0 or 0,44 are in many cases finding that their views are mis-positioned by 44 points.

Comment: Add code of what are you doing during the transitions. Moreover, add details of how your view hierarchy is made. Simulated metrics doesn't help, since they are only applied in the storyboard interface and not in the app (this is why they are called "simulated")

Comment: Thanks everyone... busy with T-Day stuff and I was not on my mac. Ill edit the question tonight with specific code and answers to questions above.

Comment: I have updated my question with the answers people asked for above.

Comment: Might be worth looking into the new property on UIViewController `edgesForExtendedLayout` and setting that to `UIRectEdgeNone`, I believe it only applies to scroll views though, so if that is not a scroll view it's not going to help.

Comment: @ChrisWagner Thanks for the suggestion. You may be on to something. I took your advice and put in in the ViewController's viewDidLoad. Ironically it jumped down from the start and stayed consistent. For now I adjusted my xib file to look fine accomodating for the wierd spacing. For now please put your comment in as an answer. Unless someone else can come up with a better solution/explanation I'll go ahead and accept your answer after the bounty ends. Not exactly the sexiest way to solve the problem but it works, and doesnt sacrifice on UI/Experience.

Comment: Do you have any autoresizing masks on your imageView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try setting the new property on UIViewController `edgesForExtendedLayout` to `UIRectEdgeNone`.

Here is a good resource that explains more about how view layouts changed in iOS 7.

[See Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html)

If you plan to be backwards compatible you will probably need to do some runtime checks and adjust positioning if the device is not running iOS 7.

Comment: This is for a iOS7 target so I wont need to do that check.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you..You can try adding `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` key and set it's value `NO` in your info.plist

```
UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = NO
```