# iOS 7 Container View Controller shows detail view controller smaller than it should be

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I made a sample project of my problem so that you can understand it better. You can get it here:

https://github.com/nwalter08/iOS-7-Container-View-Controller-Probs

My problem is that I have a `UITabBarController` that holds a `Container UIViewController` that holds a `UINavigationController` that holds a `UIViewController`. A lot I know :)

The problem is that when I run the app on iOS 7, the `UIViewController` doesn't fill the space of the whole `UINavigationController`. When I run in iOS 6, this is not a problem.

Some special notes are that I set the `translucent` property on the `tabBar` and `navigationBar` to NO. I am also not using IB or storyboards.

I have color coded the View Controllers so that you can see that the `UIViewController` is too short and the yellow `UINavigationController` background is showing.

iOS 6

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lpl6wtmoy3dsn3c/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Feb%206%2C%202014%2C%202.45.56%20PM.png

iOS 7

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f5r5oltb4ookteh/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Feb%206%2C%202014%2C%202.46.21%20PM.png

Update --
So rdelmar's answer worked for the UIViews that had no content inside them but I found with my code that the content was stretched and didn't fit. I am pretty sure this is an iOS bug and I submitted a Radar to Apple. To solve my issue, I used a UITabBarController replacement https://github.com/jinthagerman/JBTabBarController

Comment: You may need to adjust your iOS 6/7 deltas.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794037/interface-builder-what-are-the-uiviews-layout-ios-6-7-deltas-for

Comment: Ya no IB, I will mention that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the following line in the loadView method of RedContainerViewController,

```
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

It's view shouldn't be the size of the screen since it's embedded in a tab bar controller. Change that line to just `[[UIView alloc] init]`, and it should work.

Comment: DING DING DING we have a winner! Thank you!

Comment: @nickchuckwalter, and you should award the winner by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Detail view controller is not smaller. It goes under navigationBar in iOS 7. You can set navigationBar.translucent =NO or you can set delta in your xib/storyboard ( if you have one )

Comment: The `navigationBar.translucent` is already set to NO. The blue view controller is still too short.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the navigation bar to not be translucent doesn't mean that that view does not sit underneath it anymore. It just means that it's not visible underneath it anymore.

Set `edgesForExtendLayout` to `UIRectEdgeNone` on your view controller, and your view will actually move from underneath the navigation bar to the visible area of the view controller.

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't change anything. If it works for you, please do a pull request on my github project so that I can see your code.

Answer (score 0):

This fixes it, but may have other side effects you don't want.

```
--- a/TabBarContainerNavProblem/MyTabBarViewController.m
+++ b/TabBarContainerNavProblem/MyTabBarViewController.m
@@ -31,7 +31,7 @@
         BOOL isAtLeast7 = [version floatValue] >= 7.0;

         if (isAtLeast7) {
-            self.tabBar.translucent = NO;
+            self.tabBar.translucent = YES;
         }
     }
     return self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer to a similar question [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20960967/1825103).

after setting that flag, your views should position themselves as expected.